# Android: storing video file captured by the camera

Tags: android, video, android-camera

Hello I'm developing an app which uses the camera2 API. I used the Caemra2Video sample provided by Google, and during the modification I changed the file storage directory.
The original code is like this:

```
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getVideoFile(activity).getAbsolutePath());
...
private File getVideoFile(Context context) {
    return new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "video.mp4");
}
```

I changed it in this way:

```
private File getVideoFile(Context context) {

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "camera2Video");

    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d(TAG, "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

    File videoFile;

    videoFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    return videoFile;
}
```

If I record a video, there is indeed a file with the correct name inside the folder. However, whenever I open the app and start the camera activity, there will be a .mp4 file generated (no matter whether I actually record the video or not) with the size of 0. How can I modify it to avoid this? Thanks!

Comment: You have created the video file name but didnt copied data to it. Thats why this is happening

Comment: @BBdev how would you do that?